# DELPHI Edit.OnExit by TAB, show window result on focus bug

Tags: delphi

I'm having trouble with the following scenario:

- 2 Edit's
- Type something in Edit1 and press TAB, focus goes to Edit2
- Edit1.OnExit -> show a Form with a message "Processing..." (makes a lengthy validation)

After the form closes, the focus on Edit2 seems to be "crashed"... 
- the hole TEXT in Edit2 isn't selected
- the carret isn't flashing

Example:

- Create a new form
- Put 2 edits
- Set this as OnExit event in Edit1:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    with TForm.CreateNew(self) do
       try
         Width := 100;
         Height := 50;
         Position := poMainFormCenter;
         show;
         sleep(200);
       finally
         Free;
       end;
  end;
  ```
- Run the application
- Set focus in the Edit1 and press TAB

I'm using:

- Delphi 7 Enterprise
- Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure precisely what's going on here, but it looks like the order of processing of messages is a bit messed up. Instead of killing your other form with `Free`, use `Release` and the focus will behave as you desire.

Another option is to use `ShowModal` instead of `Show`. Normally you show a *processing* dialog modally because you don't want the user making modifications to the main form whilst you are processing. If you do that then you can carry on using `Free`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem. Windows has problems when you change focus before it's completed the last focus change (eg., focus starts changing from `Edit1` to `Edit2`, but `Edit1.OnExit` does something  to change focus to another control or form.

This happens, for instance, when apps try to do validations in an `OnExit` event and then try to return focus to the original control when the validation fails.

The easiest solution is to post a message to your form handle in the `OnExit` instead, and handle the focus change  need there.  It will fire once the target control gets the input focus, and Windows doesn't get confused.

```
const
   UM_EDIT1_EXITED = WM_USER + 1;

type
  TForm1=class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    procedure UMEdit1Exited(var Msg: TMessage); message UM_EDIT1_EXITED;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, UM_EDIT1_EXITED, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.UMEdit1Exited(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  // Show your other form here
end;
```

From an old Borland NG post by Dr. Peter Below of [TeamB](http://www.teamb.com):

> here is my general sermon on the "show dialog from OnExit" problem:
>
> If an OnExit handler is triggered (which happens in response to the 
>   Windows
>   message WM_KILLFOCUS) Windows is in the midst of a focus change. If you do
>   something in the handler that causes another focus change (like popping up
>   a message box or doing a SetFocus call) Windows gets terribly confused. 
>   The
>   missing cursor is a symptom of that.
>
> If you have to display a message to your user from an OnExit handler, do 
>   it
>   this way:
>
> 1. Define a constant for a user message somewhere in the INterface 
>      section
>      of your unit, above the type declaration for your form
>
>    'Const
>        UM_VALIDATE = WM_USER + 200;'
> 2. Give your Form a handler for this message, best placed in the private
>      section of the class declaration:
>
>    `Procedure UMValidate( Var Msg: TMessage ); message UM_VALIDATE;`
> 3. Post a UM_VALIDATE message to the form from the OnExit handler if
>      the contents of the field are not ok. You can pass additional 
>      information in the wparam and lparam parameters of the message, e.g.
>      an error number and the Sender object. In fact you could do the whole
>      validation in the UMValidate handler!